# How do I Get EXIF data after AJAX load of images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, exif

I'm working on a swipe-able wine image viewer for NapaWapa.com and I've got it working pretty well: http://www.tonyjacobson.com/napawapa/gallery/index.html

I'm using a jquery plugin to read the exif data of the images in the gallery. However, the plugin seems to only work when the  src attribute is hard coded — not when the images are loaded via AJAX. Can any of you experts out there take a peek at the JS (http://www.tonyjacobson.com/napawapa/gallery/js/jquery.exif.js) to see if you could recommend a change to the plugin code to recommend a fix?

Here's the specific part of the plugin code where it deals with reading the EXIF data:

```
// HTML IMG EXAMPLE
<img class="lazyOwl" data-src="images/03.jpg" exif="true" />

// JAVASCRIPT CLICK TO TEST IMG EXIF DATA
$("img").on('click', function(event){
    $(this).exifLoad();
    console.log( "HIT: " + $(this).exif('Make') );
});


// JQUERY PLUGIN CODE EXCERPT
function loadAllImages()
{
    var aImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i=0;i<aImages.length;i++) {
        if (aImages[i].getAttribute("exif") == "true") {
            if (!aImages[i].complete) {
                addEvent(aImages[i], "load",
                    function() {
                        EXIF.getData(this);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                EXIF.getData(aImages[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

// automatically load exif data for all images with exif=true when doc is ready
jQuery(document).ready(loadAllImages);

// load data for images manually
jQuery.fn.exifLoad = function(fncCallback) {
    return this.each(function() {
        EXIF.getData(this, fncCallback)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a similar question, and found assistance from this [thread](http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-frameworks/182665-display-exif-image.html). Try modifying your Javascript (not the plugin) to include this code:

```
$("img").load(function() {
  $(this).exifLoad(function() {
    // exif data should now be ready...
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... great idea. Tried it but it still didn't work. I think it's something to do with the exif is attempting to read on page load vs. on image load. Like I need to re-initialize the exif function after each image is loaded.